# не сортируется массив при использовании многопоточности

Tags: c#, многопоточность, сортировка

Задание такое:
Написать модуль сортировки, включающий в себя:
1. Метод, реализующий упорядочивание массива произвольного типа. Принцип сравнения
двух элементов должен передаваться в метод через делегат. Стандартные инструменты типа
Array.Sort и IComparable не использовать.
Продемонстрировать работу метода, упорядочив массив строк по возрастанию длины. Строки равной длины между собой упорядочивать в алфавитном порядке.
2. Метод, позволяющий запустить в сортировку в отдельном потоке выполнения;
3. Событие, сигнализирующее о завершении сортировки.
Продемонстрировать работу модуля в многопоточном режиме.

Подскажите почему при использовании отдельного потока для сортировки, массив не сортируется. И как это можно исправить?

p.s. у меня отдельно реализован метод CompareString, но там всё очевидно, поэтому не вижу смысла приводить его сюда тоже.

```
public class SortingModule<T>
{
    public event EventHandler SortingFinished;

    public void Sort(T[] arr, Func<T, T, int> compare)
    {
        if (compare == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (compare(arr[j], arr[i]) > 0)
                {
                    var tmp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }

        SortingFinished?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void CreateThreadForSorting(T[] arr, Func<T, T, int> compare)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(() => this.Sort(arr, compare));
        th.Start();
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortingModule<string> sortingModule = new SortingModule<string>();
        string[] array = new string[] {"bacd", "abcd", "ff", "rlk", "r",    "cghjk", "dghjk" };
        Func<string, string, int> compareString = CompareString;

        sortingModule.CreateThreadForSorting(array, compareString);
        sortingModule.SortingFinished += (object o, EventArgs arg) => Console.WriteLine("Sorting Finished!");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Вы не ждете окончания сортировки перед тем, как выводить массив в консоль.

Comment: Массив вообще может оказаться отсортирован до того, как Вы назначите `SortingFinished` - Вы же поток сразу запускаете внутри `CreateThreadForSorting`.

Comment: а как это исправить?

Comment: Ну если вы написали весь этот код и понимаете, что делает `SortingFinished`, ответ должен быть очевиден.

Comment: разобралась) спасибо